# How to get PHP to use internationalised dates?

Tags: php, date, internationalization

I'm trying to get PHP dates to work cross language. The language code will be supplied according to the logged in user's language setting.

I thought I could do this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%A %B %Y');
```

But the output is:

```
Wednesday April 2011
```

Whereas I would have expected:

```
Mittwoch April 2011
```

*(April is the same in English and German)*

Is this not the correct way to use the `strftime` function? If not, is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale) returns a value, which can be FALSE:

> Returns the new current locale, or
>   FALSE if the locale functionality is
>   not implemented on your platform, the
>   specified locale does not exist or the
>   category name is invalid.

So you need to check the return value.

Be aware that locale names vary depending on the platform and `de_DE.UTF-8` looks like a typical Unix name. Is it a Unix server? If so, make sure that the computer actually has such locale installed.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [**`IntlDateFormatter`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class *(PHP >= 5.3)*

Quoting the example given on the manual page of [`IntlDateFormatter::format()`][2] :

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "en_US" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
echo "First Formatted output is ".$fmt->format(0);
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "de-DE" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
echo "Second Formatted output is ".$fmt->format(0);
```

Will output :

```
First Formatted output is Wednesday, December 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM PT
Second Formatted output is Mittwoch, 31. Dezember 1969 16:00 Uhr GMT-08:00
```

Comment: More specifically (and also simpler): `\IntlDateFormatter::create('de_DE', \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE)->format(\time())`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a bit of code. The answer is found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

/* try different possible locale names for german as of PHP 4.3.0 */
$loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
echo "Preferred locale for german on this system is '$loc_de'";

?>

Answer (score 0):

Your use of strftime() appears to be correct according to the manual.  I would question your setLocale() settings.

See [here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-124789.html) for a question very similar to yours on another forum.