# Convert string into time in french - PHP

Tags: php, date

Basically I wangted to change any string that look like this `012014` into `Janvier 2014`
in french.
So Itried this and none of them worked!

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
 $pubdate = date('MY', strtotime('012014'));
 echo $pubdate;
```

Instead it displays me `May2014`, is it that it display me the current month and why is that?And how to display it in french?

Much appreciated!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430767/php-print-month-in-french?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652443/how-to-get-php-to-use-internationalised-dates?rq=1

Comment: The main issue here I guess is that why it convert it to wrong date?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the [DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0) then use strftime to output the date using a given locale

```
// Set the locale to French
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");

// Create a date object from your format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mY', '042014');

// Format the date according to locale settings
strftime("%B %Y", $date->getTimestamp());
```

Check the [strftime documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for all available formats

If this still don't work, check the presence of the given locale :

```
// Returns false if the locale is not available on your system
var_dump( setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR") );
```

Comment: Is the french locale installed on your system ? On osx / linux systems, you can check by running the terminal command : `locale -a`